# counting type of data in a row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table, named "stu_id" which contain 3 fields, like "sem_id", "crs_id", "session" with some of data.

"sem_id"(cse1/1, cse1/1, cse1/1, cse1/1, cse1/1)
"crs_id"(cse101, cse102, cse103, cse104, cse105)
"session"(spring2009, spring2009, spring2010, spring2009, spring2010)

```
![stu_id][table]
```

Now, i want to count how much type of session is there in session field (Of course here the answer will be two types). Its not like the number of "spring2009" and "spring2010" data in that field. Simply want to count the "type of session". So, what will be the mysql query for this.- Thank you.

Comment: Can u examplify it more? Exactly what do u want to count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT count(sess) from (SELECT distinct(session) as sess FROM stu_id);
```

If that's what u want... :)

Comment: @Webrider
Hey, thanks...
Accept it as an answer too, in case it works the way you like... :)

Comment: Pardon me, what does that stand for "sess"??

Comment: No need to pardon... :)
"sess" was imply an meaningless abbreviation for 'session'
in case u want to know the usage of 'sess', then:
I used multilevel query/subquery concept.
Here, 1st i queried DISTINCT SESSIONS FROM THE TABLE (inner query),
THEN, FROM the inner query, storing it's result in temporary variable 'SESS' i simply counted the no. of distinct sessions using 'COUNT' :)

Comment: is it showing some error or what?
or you are not getting desired result?

Comment: Oh! that nice. To print the type of number, is this the mysql query i have coded next    "$query = "SELECT count(sess) from (SELECT distinct(session) as sess FROM stu_id)";

  
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
echo "$result";"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5071/discussion-between-webrider-and-daredev)